# ListView with Custom Adapter [Android]

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to build a ListView with a custom layout but so far have not been able to successfully do it. I'm a beginner and have been following tutorials to get it done.
This is what I'm doing:

```
    //this is where I want the custom list items to be displayed.
    //GroupAdapter is the constructor of the class in which I'm trying to make a custom adapter
    stringArray = new String[10];
    groupItemArrayAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this,stringArray);
    groupListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    groupListView.setAdapter(groupItemArrayAdapter);

    //this is the code in GroupAdapter.java class
    public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GroupAdapter(Activity activity, String[] items){
        super(activity,R.layout.group_view);
        inflater=activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view,parent,false);
     }
    }
```

When i start the app, a blank screen appears. Initially when i used Android default layout for the list, list items were displayed but not anymore... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Here is the group_view.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="30dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Group Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/signIn"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @gio already did, doesn't help

Comment: @leMS provide xml of layout `layout.group_view`

Comment: @gio added, check it out

Comment: The Vogella stuff is great, but verbose. I find the mkyong examples useful for quickly getting my head around things. He shows you an easy to grasp example of a custom ListView here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/. It's how I figured it out. You'll be able to see quickly how to adapt his brief code to your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all your code by next

```
stringArray = new String[10];
groupItemArrayAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this,stringArray);
groupListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
groupListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.group_view, R.id.gName, stringArray));
```

it's for case when you want to show strings at `gName` field, if you want to shot them at `activity`, then you need to use

```
groupListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.group_view, R.id.activity, stringArray));
```

Answer for "Why it's blank?"

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view,parent,false);
}
```

You only inflate empty view and does not assign strings to fields. It would be (simplest version)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gName);
    String item = getItem(position)
    textView.setText(item);
    return convertView;
}
```

You'll be able to implement better version after read article [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)